# Ruby convert hash to histogram in csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
@histogram = {
  "Date 1" => [
     {"Item 1" => 1},
     {"Item 4" => 3}
  ],
  "Date 2" => [
     {"Item 2" => 7},
     {"Item 1" => 2},
     {"Item 5" => 1}
  ],
  "Date 3" => [
     {"Item 4" => 3},
     {"Item 2" => 2},
     {"Item 8" => 1},
     {"Item 1" => 5}
  ]
}
```

I want to convert that into a day by day histogram CSV file that looks like this:

```
|        | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 |
| Item 1 |   1    |   2    |   5    |
| Item 2 |        |   7    |   2    |
| Item 4 |   3    |        |   3    |
| Item 5 |        |   1    |        |
| Item 8 |        |        |   8    |
```

What's tripping me up is the fact that the `@histogram` hash can be totally out of order. The dates (`keys`) are likely to be in order, but the Items are going to be totally out of order. Moreover, as you can see, the items don't have to be the same across different dates. Where an item is not existent on a particular date, it's quantity in the histogram can be assumed to be 0.

Comment: Seems like you have to do a bit of repackaging of the contents of that hash in temp data structures to make constructing your CSV easier. Suppose you took that idea and ran with it. I wonder what kind of code you could produce.

Comment: For your first problem - you can use sort. For the second one - get the union of the keys beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much point for having array of hashes for `Date1` value, it could very well be single hash with multiple keys. The structure of your `@histogram` should preferably be like below:

```
{"Date 1"=>{"Item 1"=>1, "Item 4"=>3},
 "Date 2"=>{"Item 2"=>7, "Item 1"=>2, "Item 5"=>1},
 "Date 3"=>{"Item 4"=>3, "Item 2"=>2, "Item 8"=>1, "Item 1"=>5}}
```

Hence, I will give solution that will convert `@histogram` to above structure and build on that.

```
processed_hash = @histogram.map {|k,v| [k, v.reduce(&:merge)]}.to_h

column_headers =  processed_hash.keys
row_headers = processed_hash.flat_map{ |k, v| v.keys}.uniq.sort

print "|" + "".center(10) + "|"
column_headers.each {|ch| print ch.center(10) + "|"}
puts
row_headers.each do |rh|
  print "|" +  rh.center(10) + "|"
  column_headers.each {|ch| print processed_hash.dig(ch, rh).to_s.center(10) + "|"}
  puts
end
```

Output:

```
|          |  Date 1  |  Date 2  |  Date 3  |
|  Item 1  |    1     |    2     |    5     |
|  Item 2  |          |    7     |    2     |
|  Item 4  |    3     |          |    3     |
|  Item 5  |          |    1     |          |
|  Item 8  |          |          |    1     |
```